# Terminal If command

Tags: shell, if-statement, terminal, command

I have the following question: I have have the following code which scans and counts the amount of wifis:

```
airport en1 -s |awk 'END{print NR--}'
```

Now I want to use make terminal open an audio file in certain cases example:

```
if x >10
  then open 1.mp3
else open 2.mp3
```

How can I do that?

Comment: what does "open" mean in this context?  you want to play it, or read the data?

Comment: what is not working?

Answer (score 2):

What about reading a [simple bash tutorial](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-6.html)?

```
if [ $(airport en1 -s | awk 'END{print NR--}') -gt 13 ]; then
   open 1.mp3
else
   open 2.mp3
fi
```

In OSX there is the `open` command, in Linux you can use `xdg-open`.

Comment: I have the audiofiles located on my desktop, how do I direct the terminal there?

Comment: `open ~/Desktop/1.mp3`?